# Kill ring not synchronizing with clipboard in Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, yank, kill-ring, clipboard

I have been using Emacs 24 on Windows 7 for almost a year without any issues. But recently, kill-ring in my Emacs has stopped synchronizing with clipboard (actually whatever I copy from within Emacs is available in system's clipboard but not other way around). I've successfully used `Shift + insert` to paste things off my clipboard all the time earlier but not any more :(. I've tried adding lines below to my Emacs init script.

```
  (setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
  (setq x-select-enable-primary nil)
  ;; Treat clipboard input as UTF-8 string first; compound text next, etc.
  (setq x-select-request-type '(UTF8_STRING COMPOUND_TEXT TEXT STRING))
```

But it has not affect on the erroneous behaviour of synchronization between kill-ring and clipboard. Any help or suggestions or guidance to debug the issue would be appreciated.

## Notes

1. I'm using `arsclip` as clipboard manager.
2. I'm running Windows 7 x64 and emacs-w64.
3. I use conemu, I noticed that my clipboard is no synchronizing both ways.

Comment: Did it work with stock Emacs without any configuration? I can copy/paste both ways fine. Probably you should disable 3rd party apps that manage your clipboard to see whether it works again or not?L

Comment: I tried running stock Emacs with no customization, also disabled my clipboard manager but it still persists.

Comment: Have you tried `C-y` instead of `S-insert`?

Comment: Yes. I've checked browsed kill-ring within Emacs, but the text I copied on windows does not exist. But, if I copy something within Emacs then it appears on the kill-ring.

Comment: Are you running Emacs in GUI or in terminal? It seems like you are running Emacs in that `Conemu` terminal? If so, you should run GUI Emacs and it should work like normal desktop app.